# Reporting PHP 500 Errors

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I have a rather old procedural php site running on an IIS7.5 server - it's on a Windows box simply because it runs alongside a Classic ASP site.

The Classic ASP site has a customised 500 error page that uses Server.GetLastError to output details of the error that prompted the page. These details are then emailed to me.

In PHP, I've found `error_get_last()`, that should do similar, but I'm not sure how to set this up. Does anyone have any experience of using `error_get_last()` on an IIS7.5 server?

Can I just output the `error_get_last()` like below?

```
$error = error_get_last();
if ($error !== NULL) {
    $errno   = $error["type"];
    $errfile = $error["file"];
    $errline = $error["line"];
    $errstr  = $error["message"];
    //send the email...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: no. you can't. a 500 error from a php script means the script killed itself and barfed all over the floor. there's no error left, because the script is dead. any other script which fires up in as a handler for the 500 will NOT be able to get the internal error that caused the 500 - it's a completely independent script with its own error queue.

Comment: Marc B - thanks for confirming! I can't mark this as the answer as it's a comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't. A 500 error from a php script means the script killed itself and barfed all over the floor. There's no error left, because the script is dead. Any other script which fires up as a handler for the 500 will NOT be able to get the internal error that caused the 500 - it's a completely independent script with its own error queue.

At best you could have the error handler script parse through the server error log, but since it's a completely separate script, you couldn't reliably tell which of the errors in the log would be the one that you want to look at.